# Allow multiple contributors to one post

Tags: posts

I have been asked how easy it would be to have multiple contributors being able to submit content that would be brought into one post.

The rub is that they wouldn't be allowed to see the main post or edit the post, this would be reserved for the site admins - their role would be mainly around adding their piece of the post into the mix and that would be it.

I know this isn't standard functionality, but I don't even know where I would begin looking for a plugin - I could roll my own but if this is a solved problem then I would rather utilise that fact. So I guess my main question is *Is this a common power-user feature and what name does it go by?*

This is essentially to replace the current system that involves people emailing in content that gets copied and pasted into the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use scribu's [Posts 2 Posts plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) to relate a Custom Post Type called "Drafts" (or something else to avoid possible conflict with naming conventions reserved for Post Status). It's a very powerful plugin, allows Posts to be related to other Posts. In this way you could bring in the content of the Draft post type **into** the end product. Or just relate them for reviewing purposes. Depends on what you're really trying to do.